# How i could get all element by class name of same class?

Tags: javascript

Im triying of get all element by class name but i cannot get

when i try to get a one lement this command works

```
document.getElementsByClassName('div1')[5].value
```

but this command not works

```
var i=0;
for ( i < 6; i++) {
    x = document.getElementsByClassName('div1')[i].value ;
}
var elementHtml = x;
```

i obtain this error

SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop condition  index.html:9:16
ReferenceError: downloadDiv is not defined

i get this error also

****TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[i] is undefined[Saber más]

---

please somebody help me

=============================================================

i put the response thankyou for your answers

```
var i = 0;

var x = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName('div1').length; i++){    
    x = x + document.getElementsByClassName('div1')[i].value;
}
var elementHtml = x;
```

Comment: for(; i<6; i++) You missed semicolon as error says. You can remove var i = 0, and change for to: for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)

Comment: The standard way to define `for` is defining the index var inside:  `for (var i=0; i < 6; i++)`

Comment: i get this TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...)[i] is undefined[Saber más]

Comment: why wouldn't you just use querySelectorAll('.div1') and then loop through it and get the .value ?

Comment: im triying this too but my other command not works

Comment: there is nothing wrong with defining var i = 0 outside the for loop, some might even say it is preferable

Comment: Can you show the HTML this is supposed to operate on?

Comment: @AlekseiMaide You mean `querySelectorAll('.div1')`.

Comment: connexo yes please wait

Comment: @zero625 If `document.getElementsByClassName(...)[i]` is `undefined`, then you don’t have six elements to iterate through. Just replace the `6` by `document.getElementsByClassName('div1').length`.

Comment: yes, missed the . for the class @Xufox

Comment: works very thankyou Xufox

Comment: If you set a variable, say `var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('div1')` before the loop, you can use `elements.length` in the loop test, and `elements[i].value` to get each element's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made a mistake in your for loop in relation to your question;

```
for (var i=0; i < 6; i++) {
    x = document.getElementsByClassName('div1')[i].value;
}
var elementHtml = x;
```

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('div1') instanceof Array === false`, so `Array.prototype.forEach` will not be available. Its type is `HTMLCollection` which is *array-like*, but not actually an `array`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: @connexo Though you can foreach through a HTMLCollection I think, Well you'd have to iterate anyways using a counter. Fair enough.